# Adding a unique identifier to EKEvent

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, identifier, ekevent

In my app I'm creating an `EKEvent` to mark an appointment I make from server data, and then I add it to the phone's main calendar.
Doing that, I would like to save the appointment's Id in the calendar so that I can fetch it easily.
While exploring the `EKEvent` object, I found the `eventIdentifier` property, but it is `readOnly` so I cannot assign value to it.
Is there a way to add custom properties (like Id) to an `EKEvent`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add some additional fields to EKEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550287/how-to-add-some-additional-fields-to-ekevent)

Comment: @the4kman Not sure the question is a duplicate, but the answer surely can be applicable. Thanks!